# Extension for Azure data studio that run after execute query

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-extensions, azure-data-studio

Is there an event that can be listened after run the query?
If not, can i subscribe keybinding event on "F5" but that the query run first, and then my extension?

UPDATE:

I partly solved the second option.

i looked on keyboard shortcuts and i got command ID by action run query
[image]

and i was try executeCommand by this command ID:
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('runQueryKeyboardAction');

I don't know how it happened but it works. Now i have a question, how i can get message from this executeCommand about result of execution query.